# performance decreses after 45k record, when rewriting excel (.xlsm) file from java resultset

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-poi, resultset, xlsm

This code works perfectly for records below 35k and write data on Sheet but if record exist 45k performance slow down and dead without any exception or error,
and doesn't create any file.

how can i overcome this issue?

```
public void dbConnect(String driver_connect_string, String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password){
    try{ 

        //database connectivity

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        String queryString = propq.getProperty("Query");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File(("sourceFile")));
         XSSFWorkbook wb_template;
         wb_template = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
         System.out.println("package loaded");

         Sheet  sheet = wb_template.getSheetAt(0);
         Row row = null;
         int index = 1;
         while (rs.next()) {
             try{
              row = sheet.createRow(index);
              row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString(1));    
              row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString(2));    
              row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rs.getString(3)); 
              .
              .
              row.createCell(23).setCellValue(rs.getString(25));

              System.out.println(index);

             }
             catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println(e);
             }
              index++;
          }

         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(("destFile")));
         wb_template.write(out);
         out.flush();
         out.close();  

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678164/saving-sxssf-as-xls-file

Comment: what was the issue in the code here that the answer in your comment addresses?